# Stop Swing Timer After N Executions

Tags: java, swing, timer

I wrote this Swing timer that is supposed to run 10 times and then stop. However, the compiler says `Timer` is not initialised. I do not want to initialise it and I don't need to ([here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/Timerstop.htm) is an example where it is not initialised and it works). What is wrong?

```
public Enhanced() {
    Timer picTimer ;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 422);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    JLabel lblTimer = new JLabel();
    lblTimer.setBounds(361, 67, 61, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblTimer);

    ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
        int time=0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            System.out.println("hello");

            if (++time > 10) {
                picTimer.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    };
    picTimer = new Timer(1000,a);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct Timer? 'javax.swing.Timer', you may have accidentally imported 'java.util.Timer' instead

Comment: `timer` in the linked example is an instance variable, so it's initialized to `null`, and also the listener has access to it (so the `Timer` instance can be created later). In your example it's an uninitialized local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the declaration for `picTimer` to class level so that the variable is not required to be initialized within the local scope of the constructor

Comment: You don't "have" to, the `ActionEvent#getSource` will return a reference to the `Timer` which call `actionPerformed`, just saying ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is a way in which you can avoid referring the external timer variable.

The timer is actually the *source* of the event your `ActionListener` receives every time. Therefore, you can access it by calling `e.getSource()`.

This way, you don't even need to declare the timer in advance:

```
ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
    int time=0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        System.out.println("hello");

        if (++time > 10) {
            Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
            timer.stop();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
};

new Timer(1000,a).start();
```

Note that calling `System.exit()` like that will stop the timer anyway. It's really not recommended calling `System.exit()` like that.

Answer (score 2):

In that example you link to, `timer` is a *field*, whereas in your code it's a *local variable*. You can solve your issue in at least two ways:

1. Make `timer` a field like in the example.
2. Create the timer with `null` initial listener, so that you can refer to the actual timer instance when creating the action listener. Then use [Timer.addActionListener()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) to add the listener.